# Categorical series to dataframe of categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have a series of categorical values:

```
y = [A , A , B, C]
```

I want to convert it to a data frame, with column per category and 1 if this category exists:

```
df = [A B C]
     [1 0 0]
     [1 0 0]
     [0 1 0]
     [0 0 1]
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `list`:

```
y = ['A','A','B','C']

df = pd.get_dummies(y)
```

Or [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(y),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
```